# Android App Continuously performing heap operations

Tags: android, heap-memory

> 11-14 13:18:47.871 14235-14387/com.example.example D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 14121K, 36% free 17900K/27708K, paused 47ms, total 47ms
>
> 11-14 13:18:47.871 14235-14387/com.example.example I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 24.392MB for 5785374-byte allocation

These two operations are continuously going on in my android app. No other operations are happening. I do not know what code I need to share for this. I am really sorry for that. Please let me know what code to share for this.

```
private static String uncompressInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    String value = "";
    byte buffer[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    GZIPInputStream gzipIn = null;
    try {
        gzipIn = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream,BUFFER_SIZE);
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = gzipIn.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            value += new String(buffer,0,bytesRead);
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            if (gzipIn != null) {
                gzipIn.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: The operations are happening for over 3-4 minutes

Comment: Are you loading way too much images or passing heavy data between components?

Comment: I am trying to decompress a heavy gzip file.

Comment: that could be the reason, try to optimize decompression and check if you are performing any redundant task that can be simply cached

Comment: I have added the code too. I will try to optimise it further.

Comment: When are u calling this? very frequently? with same data?

Comment: Can u please close this question if you know the fix now or rephrase your question with specific problem and answer it on your own for future community reference :)

Comment: Sure, I will check the solution once and answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that with the available RAM and the malloc operations being continuously performed for allocating memory, the GC was also running to free up the memory continuously so that more space can be freed. In a normal case 1 string character is 1 byte but when you use malloc to use it at the runtime, the string character is being allocated an average of 18 bytes. The string which was being used here was of over 3.5 million characters which for a particular phone was becoming more than something which can be handled. I separated the string into small chunks while receiving the stream to resolve the problem.